# Puppeteer `dragleave`

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I'm currently using element.dragEnter() to test if the state changes of my react component.
It runs perfectly fine.

Now to test a step later, what would be the equivalent of `dragLeave` to get the state to go back to what it was?

Here's my code for firing the drag entry.

```
test('handles dragOver and dragLeave', async function (){
const element = await page.$('[data-box="true"]');
await element.dragEnter(this, {dataTransfer: {
            files: []
}});
expect(await page.$('[data-dragOver="true"]')).not.toBeNull();
});
```

I've many concepts ranging from page.evaluate() to simulating mouse up down functions, etc but no luck.

Thanks!